# PHPmyadmin: Choose what image to display on a certain table field?

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I'm making a database for a news and updates section in my website. I've succesfully created a table with fields for the title, the time, post number, text etc.. but there's one field that I don't know how to create:

I want a field in my table which displays just a tiny image of the admin that posted the update. We are 4 admins. I don't know if there's a way to let each admin choose his photo when writing an update. I think it has something to do with setting different ID's for each image? I've also read that uploading an image to a database (BLOB) is a bad idea, how do I use images in a database then?

Something like this example:

[image: http://i49.tinypic.com/14t21pl.jpg]

Im kind of new to this PHP environment, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay

Answer (score 1):

You're quite right in saying that it's bad practise to store images on database tables. The better option would be to store address of these images in tables and then associate each image with an admin's username and call it up every time that admin updates posts.